# VBA SUMIFS Macro with Criteria from multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on trying to write a Macro that will use the `SUMFIS` formula; here is what I have so far:

```
Sub SumCodes()

Dim BL1 As Worksheet, Jan As Worksheet
Dim Code As Range, Shift As Range, Month As Range, Seconds As Range, OutPut As Range, HeadCode As Range

Set BL1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BL1")
Set Jan = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jan")
Set Code = BL1.Range("D2:D")
Set Shift = BL1.Range("I2:I")
Set Month = BL1.Range("C2:C")
Set Seconds = BL1.Range("G2:G")
Set OutPut = Jan.Range("C3:CO3")
Set HeadCode = Jan.Range("C2:CO2")

OutPut = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Seconds, Code, HeadCode, Month, "=Jan", Shift, "=1")

End Sub
```

I have about 30,000 rows and the `OutPut` needs to be in a range based on the header of the output column. I don't want to just enter the formula in each cell since there are so many entries. I cannot attach the excel workbook, since it is so large; but here is a couple screen clippings of what it looks like:

[image]

[image]

So what I am trying to do:

I want the Macro to `sum` the numbers if `Column G` of the worksheet `BL1` if the entry in `BL1 column D` is the same as the header of worksheet `Jan (C2)` and if the Month (column C) in `BL1` is "Jan" and if the Shift (column I) in `BL1` is 1. I will want to change this eventually to every month of the year, for 3 shifts.

When I run the code I have I get a

> Run-Time Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

I've tried looping, but I get the same error. I'm not very familiar with VBA, I typically code with Python; so any help I can get in the way of fixing this code and understanding why it isn't working would be very helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `"D2:D"` is not a valid range. You either use an entire column `"D:D"` or add an end row number. Same for the other columns.

Comment: Alright, I see why that would work. So For ' C3:CO3 ' and ' C2:CO2 ' I would have to use it as a loop? I wasn't thinking it through when I deleted the row index and filled up 100,000 entries.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an SQL solution available in Excel for Windows. But first you need to adjust your month columns from its current wide format with reason codes in separate columns to long format with reason codes in one column of different values. Use various transpose procedures to do so, starting in `A1` cell.

```
Month Code Reason Code   Value
Jan   BL1          102   28242 
Jan   BL1          104       0
Jan   BL1          106       0
Jan   BL1          110       0
...
```

From there run a simple aggregate SQL join query between both worksheets and output your results to a new worksheet.

**SQL** *(embedded below, adjust column names as needed)*

```sql
SELECT b.[Reason Code] As [Header_Code], b.[End Date] As [Month], 
       SUM(b.[Reason Duration (Seconds)]) As Total_Seconds
FROM [BL1$] b
INNER JOIN [JanLong$] j
   ON b.[Reason Code] = j.[Reason Code]
   AND b.[End Date] = j.[Month]
WHERE b.[Shift] = 1  AND j.[Code] = 'BL1'
GROUP BY b.[Reason Code], b.[End Date]
```

**VBA** *(SQL results for BL1/January dumped into existing blank tab RESULTS)*

```vb
Sub RunSQL()    
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' CONNECTION STRINGS
    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm;"

    strSQL = " SELECT b.[Reason Code] As [Header_Code], b.[End Date] As [Month]," _
            & "       SUM(b.[Reason Duration (Seconds)]) As Total_Seconds" _
            & " FROM [BL1$] b" _
            & " INNER JOIN [JanLong$] j" _
            & "    ON b.[Reason Code] = j.[Reason Code]" _
            & "   AND b.[End Date] = j.[Month]" _
            & " WHERE b.[Shift] = 1 AND j.[Code] = 'BL1'" _
            & " GROUP BY b.[Reason Code], b.[End Date]"

    ' OPEN CONNECTION & RECORDSET
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' COLUMN HEADERS
    For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
        Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(1, i) = rst.Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next i        
    ' DATA ROWS
    Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close: conn.Close    
    Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing    
End Sub
```

---

**Scalability**

Now to run across all months and all BL's, ideally, you append all BL* worksheets into one tab and all long-format month worksheets into another tab, then run one master SQL statement. Of course this further suggests use of an actual database. MS Access (.accdb) databases can come in handy and is available on **all** Windows machines even without the Office program installed.

With this approach, you avoid needing to re-run individually by reason codes and months. But be sure to add a new column in *BL_Master_Data* to indicate *BLI_Code*: *BL1, BL2, ...*. See adjusted SQL with extended `SELECT`, `JOIN`, and `GROUP BY` clauses:

```sql
SELECT b.[BLI_Code], b.[Reason Code] As [Header_Code], b.[End Date] As [Month], 
       SUM(b.[Reason Duration (Seconds)]) As Total_Seconds
FROM [BL_Master_Data$] b
INNER JOIN [Month_Master_Data$] m
   ON b.[Reason Code] = m.[Reason Code]
   AND b.[End Date] = m.[Month]
   AND b.[BLI_Code] = m.[Code]               -- ADDED JOIN
WHERE b.[Shift] = 1
GROUP BY b.[BLI_Code], b.[Reason Code], b.[End Date]
```